# How do you properly call a conditional based on the intent's displayName for dialogflow?

Tags: json, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am trying to do webhook fulfillment for my dialogflow agent. However there are four specific intents that should all have different JSON responses based on what specific intent is called. Right now I am creating a switch case based on the called intent's displayName. However that is not working. Should I be using a different parameter to check what intent is called other than `displayName`?

HERE IS MY CODE THAT ONLY OUTPUTS "test"

```
server.post("/get-bill-details", function(req, res) {

let intentName = req.body.queryResult.intent.displayName;

let ret = "test";

if(intentName == "1 - Bill"){
    ret = "your billing amount is $120.";
}

return res.json({
    fulfillmentText: ret,
    source: "get-bill-details"
});
```

});

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening when it is "not working". What is the value of `intentName` when you are testing it?

Comment: your way of getting `intentName` is correct, could you clarify whats not working?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use client libraries as they will ease out the process of parsing the JSON and reduce your development time. You can use [NodeJS](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) or Python clients for Dialogflow. Also, if you need Google Assistant, you can also use following [NodeJS](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) library to build webhook. They all have documentation on how to build webhooks on cloud or by using Express and other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching with intent name give your intent an action name( try not to give any spaces e.g *input.welcome* ).

[image]

Then get the action parameter using

```
let action = req.body.queryResult.action;
switch(action) {
   your logic..
}
```

Also as abhinav said you can use [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) library to ease your development time and better readability of your code that also help cross platform response for Cards, Image and Suggestions.

```
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
server.post('/', function (request, response, next) {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    const welcome = () => {
       agent.add('Hello Welcome To My bot');
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
}
```